# jQuery pluggin -> Zepto; $.fn.extend is undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, zepto

I am new to zepto, and am using it as a jQuery replacement for the mobile part of a website.

So zepto doesn't have $.fn.extend. Fine that's cool with me, but I need my pluggin to work regardless of jquery or zepto.

What is zepto's alterative to fn.extend? How would you go about making a cross library extension? I've yet to find any documentation on this.

```
 $.fn.extend({
     lineRedNAddClass : function(option){
         $(this).css('border','red 1px solid').addClass(option);   
     }
 });
```

can this be made to work with both from the same script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zepto's extend function can be accessed via `$.extend()`, which is also available in the jQuery API, so we can simply extend `$.fn` using that.

**Example:**

```
$.extend($.fn, {
    myFunc: function() {
        $(this).css({
            color: 'red'
        });
    }
});
```

And here's a demo. I've loaded both libraries in to the assets, so just switch the value of $ using the top two lines. There's a `consle.log` included to prove that the correct library is loaded.

http://jsfiddle.net/WNTXY/

Comment: I just did and excepted, shweeet.

Answer (score 8):

in other words, to make some jquery plugins work with zepto, i've added these 2 lines to the end of my zepto.js:

```
jQuery = Zepto;
$.fn.extend = function(obj) {
    $.extend($.fn, obj);
};
```

Comment: simple and elegant!