# jQuery Hammer.js does not seem to work with Zepto

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto, hammer.js

I am trying to use jQuery.Hammer.js with Zepto v1.1.3. But for some reason I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Here is part of my code:

```
var element = $('#wrapper'); //document.getElementById('main');
console.log(element);
element.hammer({prevent_default: false, stop_browser_behavior: false}).on("dragleft"...
```

The console.log(element) is giving me:

```
[div#wrapper.hfeed, selector: "#wrapper", forEach: function, reduce: function, push: function, sort: function…]
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [official documentation](http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/), the syntax is a bit different:

```
var hammertime = new Hammer(myElement, myOptions);
    hammertime.on('pan', function(ev) {
    console.log(ev);
});
```

To use it thew way you do, i.e. `element.hammer...` you need the [jQuery plugin for Hammer.js](https://github.com/hammerjs/jquery.hammer.js)

Is that all? Not really, if you check the [source](https://github.com/hammerjs/jquery.hammer.js/blob/master/jquery.hammer.js) of this plugin, you see these two lines:

Line 9: `jQuery(this.element).triggerHandler({`

Line 25: `})(jQuery, Hammer, "hammer");`

The problem is that Zepto does not recognize `jQuery`. You could rename the occurences by `Zepto` but a better solution is [the one defined by gondo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17847420/994820):

```
jQuery = Zepto;
$.fn.extend = function(obj) {
    $.extend($.fn, obj);
};
```

Your code would then become:

```
<script src="/path/to/zepto.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/hammer.js"></script>
<script>
    // We load this code _before_ jquery.hammer.js
    jQuery = Zepto; // We just need this one line
</script>
<script src="/path/to/jquery.hammer.js"></script>
<script>
    var element = $('#wrapper');
    element.hammer({prevent_default: false, stop_browser_behavior: false}).on("dragleft", function(e)...
</script>
```